# Windows Media Center command line options?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-media-center

Is there a command line interface to Windows Media Center in Windows 7. I have an SSH daemon installed on my media center box and would love to be able log in via SSH and get the list of upcoming recordings.  As it is, I need to use Remote Desktop and then tell Media Center to run in GDI mode to display the upcoming recordings which is slow and cumbersome.

Here are interesting commands that I'm wondering about:

- List upcoming recordings
- List most recent recordings
- Status of scheduler

I'd rather not have to install Remote Potato to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm afraid command-line options are rare, coming from MS. I've never heard of any for MCE but it would be useful, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.onev.com/documentation/mccv3commands.pdf

Visit above URL from there you will get idea about general Command List

Comment: These are instructions for voice command of Media Center, not command line.  Interesting, but not quite what I was looking for.